# Calculating the tension in a string in a soap film

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

> There is a horizontal film of soap solution. On it, a thread is placed in the form of a loop. The film is punctured inside the loop and the thread becomes a circular loop of radius $R$. If the surface tension of the soap solution be $S$, then the tension in the thread will be?

[image]

I tried to do it using projected length which went like this:

Horizontal force due to surface tension:$S\times 2R(projected\ length)$

So for equilibrium: $2T=S\times 2R$

I got tension as $S\times R$ but it's wrong by a factor of 2.

[image]

Everything I did seems reasonable to me where have I gone wrong? If this problem can not be done like this could an alternative method be suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to multiply a factor of 2 because the film has two surfaces, so the surface tension = 2S.

Calculation:
Surface tension force = $$2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}S R d\theta cos\theta=4SR$$ where $\theta$ is measured from the x-axis. So $$2T=4SR$$ we have $$T=2SR$$

Comment: Darn, that's it? If someone could confirm it that would be great.

Comment: The thickness of the film is finite so you always have two surfaces(both are in contact with air) and each surface contributes to the surface tension.

Comment: This always stumped me what if the film was only a layer thick? Would the question have to mention that?

Comment: I think it's unrealistic to consider a film without any thickness. If the film itself is an ideal surface then it seems meaningless to talk about surface tension of a surface.

Comment: Actually it’s a little more complicated than that. You need to get an answer $F_T = 2RS$ which is the surface tension force. It is not that hard to calculate. Start by considering a small length segment of the loop $\Delta L = R \theta$ and write an expression for $F$ based on these parameters and $S$, $F_T$.

Comment: Yes, I tried to edit the answer and see if you agree with it.